# Applying Tint value to RGB color (PowerPoint)

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, rgb, tint

I am parsing PowerPoint file and trying read colors used.
Following is small part from parsed ppt file. Here I am trying to get proper RGB color.

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
    <a:tint val="75000"/>
</a:schemeClr>
```

So here original RGB Color is - 45555F(R-36,G-85,B-95)
Tint value applied is 75%

Desired color after applying tint has to be - 94999D(R-148,G-153,B-157)

I tried multiple algorithms from following reference links but not getting desired output, Can anyone explain how to apply Tint to RGB and get resultant RGB color values

https://saturncloud.io/blog/c-algorithm-to-tint-a-color-a-certain-percent/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.colortype.tint?view=openxml-2.8.1

[Given an RGB value, how do I create a tint (or shade)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615002/given-an-rgb-value-how-do-i-create-a-tint-or-shade)

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to this question from following 2 reference links

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f6d26f2c-114f-4a0d-8bca-a27442aec4d0/tint-and-shade-elements?forum=oxmlsdk#697a93fd-4a35-42f0-ae3f-1d261a853067

[Need help in understanding a code fragment to apply tint and shade in open office xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628532/need-help-in-understanding-a-code-fragment-to-apply-tint-and-shade-in-open-offic)

Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, that first link is me, from years ago. sRGB > linearRGB > (your tint calc) > sRGB